# How do we understand Jerry Fodor's representational theory of mind (RTM)?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, linguistics

Representational theory of mind (RTM). Hypothesis that mental processes defined over the syntax of mental representations. The later is the hypothesis that propositional attitudes are relations between subjects and mental representations.Take these two and how rational thought and behaviour can be produced by physical object, into the human brain?

Comment: This is called Brentano’s Problem and Fodor's take is addressed in Lycan's notes linked in the answer to your previous question on Fodor's Language of Thought http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/26545/fodors-language-of-thought/26574#26574

Comment: You are correct, but I want little more ideas about Fodor's representational theory and how he concluded that syntax of the mental representations that make up the language of thought?

Comment: It seems that you're conflating RTM and CTM (computational theory of mind). RTM is simply about the representation of information (be it knowledge, beliefs, etc.) Once you get into the "processes" that Fodor discusses - i.e., syntactically-derived transformations from one state to another - you are now in the realm of CTM. This was derived, practically verbatim, from how digital computational processes work. Nevertheless, it's not clear what exactly your question is, unless you literally want someone to explain Fodor's theories regarding RTM and CTM, which would be quite an undertaking.